# License key for BigQuery JDBC Driver?

Tags: google-bigquery, simba

BigQuery's website features a new JDBC driver from Simba downloadable from GCS at https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/partners/simba-drivers/.  The documentation states that a license (.lic) file needs to be installed with the JARs, but there is no place on the Google site to download the license.  How do I get one?

Answer (score 2):

This is an issue with the documentation that will be amended in the next release, no license is required.